# Get caret position (character index) in input field on drop event (FF, Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want an input field to accept only numbers, so, among other techniques, I also prevented the default drop event, if the result in the input filed is not a correct number. To achieve this, in IE I focus the field where I'm dropping the text, I search for the cursor position (character index), then construct the new value, from the old one and the dragged text.

To get caret position:

**IE:** `Math.abs(document.selection.createRange().moveStart("character", -1000000))` Works

**FF, Chrome:** `inputfield.selectionStart` Does not work

Any ideas how can I get the character index in the drop handler?

Comment: No idea why your code doesn't work, but may I suggest a simpler way to solve your problem? Instead of handling all possible events just have a timer that checks the content of the field periodically and reverts it to the last known good value in case it isn't a valid number.

Comment: It might not work as the cursor is not really there at the moment, the event being a mouse event. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of discussion around how drag/drop support is implemented in browsers but the truth is they want to keep things protected. I mean theoretically you can call

```
event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", newValue)
```

inside your drop handler but it won't work due to "security reasons" they say. It's a pity since this would have been the best solution for you, I mean changing the text before it would have been dropped.

Instead I think you can overcome your problem with a small "hack"

```
<input id="target" type="text" value="aaa bbb ccc" />
<input id="source" type="text" value="good bad" />
```

and js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var drop = false;
        $("#target").bind("drop", function (e) {
            // you can store the dragged text if you like
            //var text = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            drop = true;
        });
        $("#target").bind("focus", function (e) {
            if (drop) {
                // you can get caret here, etc
                $("#target").val($("#target").val().replace("bad", ""));
                drop = false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Tested in Chrome but it should work in all browsers too.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you, almost perfect solution, just needed to change the focus event to input, otherwise the target object's current value in the focus handler would have been still the old value, without the dragged text.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Another solution, still a hack, would be to use setTimeout([fn to parse the updated text], 100) in the drop handler. This is like an afterDrop event that doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

Visit the following Link

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/GJVG2laTaUo

I think it is usefull for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not the kind of answers we want to have here. Please explain what you're suggesting and provide some code examples.